# How to deal with temporary items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that loads messages as a regular messenger - after scrolling too close to top. I need to put there a `circle loading indicator` as the loading continues and remove it after it is finished and add loaded messages.

How do I create and delete such indicator?

Comment: Add item to the list, notifyItemInserted, load data, remove loading item, notifyItemRemoved, add newly loaded data.

Comment: Do you mean that , you need the function of a SwipeRefreshLayout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, then besides view holders with message itself, you also need a view holder with a progress bar in it, which appears and disappears. You can go with different approaches:
**a**) use Android [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview),
**b**) use third-party libraries like FastAdapter, Epoxy and so on,
**c**) write your own code

First two options already support mentioned in your question functionality, but I will be focused on the third option in this answer.
You'll have to add:

1. a scroll listener which will detect when you're almost at the top/bottom of the list [take a look at this example](https://guides.codepath.com/android/endless-scrolling-with-adapterviews-and-recyclerview)
2. adapter which works with [two types of view holders](https://droidbyme.medium.com/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-multiple-view-holder-af798458763b)
3. adapter which supports DiffUtil - you can use native Android [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter) (we don't want to have a lagging view)

Let's say you have a bunch of data - `mutableListOf(messages)`. Before getting a new list of messages from your server, you can add to this list a new message model (with empty fields or you could add some kind of optional field in your Message data class like `viewItem = MessageItem` or `viewItem = ProgressItem` to use it later in `getItemViewType()`) and then send this list (your list of models + progress model at the end of the list) to adapter. When you get a response from your server, you can just set the whole new list to adapter - DiffUtil will take care of all needed changes and will remove the item with the progress bar.

Happy coding!